# how can i run this select to_char('01-jan-2016',day dd ddspth month yyyy) from dual; why to_date function not give output to our desire format?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

Why this query not run on oracle `select to_date('01-jan-2016',day dd ddspth month yyyy) from dual;`? Why date function not give output to our desire format?

Why `to_char` function not run in at runtime? Why it run only in in any attribute like `sysdate` or `else`?

I know `select to_char(to_date('01-jan-2016',day-month-yyyy) from dual;` is run on oracle but I want to run only this at runtime without any specific attribute like this `select to_char('01-jan-2016',day-month-yyyy) from dual;`. Same case is for `to_date` function.

Comment: don't run what a prank by gordon linoff select to_date(date '2016-01-01', 'day dd ddspth month yyyy')
from dual;

Answer (score 1):

> Why this query not run on oracle `select to_date('01-jan-2016',day dd
>   ddspth month yyyy) from dual;`? Why date function not give output to
>   our desire format?

The query will not run because you violate the proper syntax. It is almost as easy to check the Oracle documentation as it is to post questions here. `to_date` takes a string parameter, which you did fine. `'01-jan-2016'` is fine. The second argument should tell the compiler exactly what format was used for the string. Your string is `'01-jan-2016'` but you gave the format model `'day dd ddspth month yyyy'` - there is no connection between that and `'01-jan-2016'`. Not Oracle's fault (or anyone's fault on this Forum), so you could ask more nicely.

Your format is `dd` (day, two digits), then dash (`-`), then short form of month name in English, all lower-case letters, then dash (`-`), then year (four digits). The correct mask for this is `'dd-mon-yyyy'` Try this:

```
select to_date('01-jan-2016', 'dd-mon-yyyy') from dual;
```

A couple of things about this. First, this solution assumes your session date language is English or American or such; if it's Italian or Chinese, `jan` will not be recognized as a valid month name (short form). If in fact you get an error message Ora-01843, "not a valid month", first check to make sure jan is spelled correctly, and then check your NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE parameter.

Second, you ask about "date function" giving "output to our desired format." Please learn more about the difference between dates and character strings. Dates do not have a format. Strings do. The call to `to_date()` the way you wrote the query will show you a date, not a string. It will show it to you according to your NLS_DATE_FORMAT parameter. You can check both your NLS parameters mentioned here with `select * from nls_session_parameters;`

If you want to input a date in the format `'01-jan-2016'` and you want the result to be another string, showing the same date but in a different format, you must first translate the string `'01-jan-2016'` to a date - I showed you how to do that above. Then, you must put this inside a call to `to_char()`, which will take the date and present it as a string, in whatever (other) format you want. Like this:

```
select to_char(to_date('01-jan-2016', 'dd-mon-yyyy'), 'day dd ddspth month yyyy') 
from   dual;
```

The result looks like this (note the column name - if you don't use an alias in the `select` statement, you'll get garbage names just like that):

```
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01-JAN-2016','DD
---------------------------------
friday    01 first january   2016
```

Note the many spaces between `friday` and `01`. The format model 'day' creates a string of length equal to the longest day-of-the-week name in English. That would be 9, the length of Wednesday. Shorter names are padded to the right with blank spaces to that max length. Note also the names friday and january, both lower-case; if you want capitalized initial (as is customary in English), you should use Day and Month instead of day and month in the format mask.

Finally, your query has another mistake. The format mask must be a string (enclosed in single quotes). You didn't do that, so you would get an error message just for that, even if everything else was correct.

I didn't understand your second and third paragraphs (which very likely means they are nonsensical, since my English is pretty good); if you rewrite them so they make sense, you may still get volunteers willing to help you, especially if you show more respect. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The output format is a string so it requires quotes, so did you try:

```
select to_char('01-jan-2016', 'day dd ddspth month yyyy')
from dual;
```

Or as I prefer:

```
select to_char(date '2016-01-01', 'day dd ddspth month yyyy')
from dual;
```

And the right function is `to_char()`, not `to_date()`.

Comment: what a joke by gordon linoff select to_date(date '2016-01-01', 'day dd ddspth month yyyy')
from dual; dont run how sad

Comment: @rajpootrana:  Please explain why you think the answer is a joke.

Comment: because it don't execute on oracle

Comment: @gordonlinoff - don't think `to_char` will work on a string?? (Re: your first solution.) You probably meant to wrap `'01-jan-2016'` within `to_date`. It would help to test your solutions before posting as it is not the first time you post solutions that have syntax errors. Not good from one of the top reputation members on the forum.